# How can I copy the property of an object in an array to another object in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to insert element of an array to another array. I have two arrays name a and b i want to take the order quantity from array a and insert it into the object of array b: here are the arrays

```
var a = [{
  "order_id": "241918",
  "product_id": "152737",
  "order_qty": "1",
  "customer_note": "Only nappy pants subsitutes please",
  "out_of_stock": "find_best_match",
  "cust_sub_prod_id": null,
  "cust_sub_prod_qty": null
}]

 var b = [{
  "id": "282",
  "product_id": "152737",
  "sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8",
  "prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg",
  "image_url": "https://www.onecart.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/108890_EA.jpg",
  "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
  "price": "40.69"
}]
```

Comment: You'd typically need to make an effort before asking. Array manipulation is well-covered on SO and elsewhere. What have you tried?

Comment: Just so you know, your arrays have just one element, which is a dict.

Comment: As Nitin Pawar pointed out, your arrays have just one element. You seem to be actually asking about *[object property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)* manipulation. I suggest you do a little reading and ask again when you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure is it the right way to do that but you can use `forloop` to achieve the same the code ex with your data is as:

```js
var a = [{
  "order_id": "241918",
  "product_id": "152737",
  "order_qty": "1",
  "customer_note": "Only nappy pants subsitutes please",
  "out_of_stock": "find_best_match",
  "cust_sub_prod_id": null,
  "cust_sub_prod_qty": null
}]

 var b = [{
  "id": "282",
  "product_id": "152737",
  "sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8",
  "prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg",
  "image_url": "https://www.onecart.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/108890_EA.jpg",
  "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
  "price": "40.69"
}]


for(var i=0 ; i< a.length; i++)
{
    var oc = a[i].order_qty;
    b[i].order_qty = oc;
}

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

both are one-element arrays containing one plain object
so with b[0] you access the fisrt and only element (object)
and .order_qty allows you to access the property needed.

```
b[0].order_qty = a[0].order_qty;
```

Comment: Code-only answers should be accompanied by an explanation of what you are doing and the assumptions you made.

Answer (score 0):

### If you doesn't care about performance

1.If you are not sure is array B have an object which match the product_id

```
a.forEach((from)=>{
    //search is there any matching object in array B
    let to = b.find(searching=>from.product_id === searching.product_id);
    if(to!=null){
       to.order_qty = from.order_qty
    }
});
```

2. If you sure that array B have an object which match the product_id

```
a.forEach((from)=>b.find(searching=>from.product_id === searching.product_id).order_qty = from.order_qty);
```

---

### If your array size will quite large and you care about performance:

Oh, seem you have better to use other data structure to store your data instead of Array.

**Okay, but why?**

The complexity of `Array.prototype.find()` is O(n), which mean when the length of your array is 1000, then the worst case will cause the `find()` loop inside your array 1000 times.

When the array A and B both have n objects inside it, using the above solutions will loop your array B n^2 times.

- when n = 100, search 10000 times is required
- when n = 1000, search 1000000 times is required
- when n = 10000, search 100000000 times is required

**How to solve it?**

Most of the javascript engine implement the Map with the hash table, so that the complexity of 
`Map.prototype.get()` is O(1), no matter your Map have 1k, 10k, 100k objects, searching an object using its key only required 1 time.

```
//Creating data
let a = new Map();
let b = new Map();

a.set("152737",{
  "order_id": "241918",
  "product_id": "152737",
  "order_qty": "1",
  "customer_note": "Only nappy pants subsitutes please",
  "out_of_stock": "find_best_match",
  "cust_sub_prod_id": null,
  "cust_sub_prod_qty": null
});

b.set("152737",{
  "id": "282",
  "product_id": "152737",
  "sku": "b175a9ea5f4d9b4766e74079c2bec8",
  "prod_name": "PnP Baby Marrows 1kg",
  "image_url": "https://www.onecart.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/108890_EA.jpg",
  "vendor": "Pick n Pay",
  "price": "40.69"
})


//Search and insert data
a.forEach(from =>{
    if(b.has(from.product_id)){
        b.get(from.product_id).order_qty = from.order_qty
    }
})
```